# Why is there a SQL_SAFE_UPDATE error on my query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL 5.6.  In my application on a certain window I have the following:

```
qry2 =      'UPDATE `listprojects` SET   `autoassign` = %i WHERE `number` = "%s" '  %(  autoassign, autoassign2)
system.db.runUpdateQuery(qry2)
```

where number is unique in the table, though not indexed.  This is throwing an error despite the UPDATE statement only updating a single row.

How can I make it so this query doesn't get caught by SQL_SAFE_UPDATES?  Do I have to make the number column an index or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-tips.html#safe-updates) explains why you can get this error even when you have a `WHERE` clause:

> With `--safe-updates`, you can modify rows only by **specifying the key values** that identify them, or a `LIMIT` clause, or both

If you don't have an index on the `number` column, then you're not specifying a key value.

Add an index on the column and the error should go away.

Comment: Ok thanks, I wasn't sure if making something an index was the same as a key value.  Good to know.

Comment: yes, MySQL uses the terms "index" and "key" interchangeably.